# MySQL stored procedure value of variable returns to null after loop ends

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, concatenation

Here is my simplified, the value of rent_ids string returns to null after the loop. I already know that the loop is working properly and that the value of rent_ids changes with every itiration.

```
BEGIN 

DECLARE rent_ids VARCHAR(265);
DECLARE tmp_rent_id int;
create temporary table due_rent_ids (rent_id int);
SET rent_ids = "";

set @test = "Insert into due_rent_ids (rent_id) select unit_id from tbl_rent";

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @test; 

EXECUTE stmt1; 

BEGIN   

        DECLARE cur1 CURSOR for select rent_id from due_rent_ids;
        OPEN cur1;

        read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur1 INTO tmp_rent_id;

            IF rent_ids = "" THEN
              SET rent_ids = tmp_rent_id;
            ELSE
              SET rent_ids = concat(rent_ids, ", ", tmp_rent_id);
            END IF;

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE cur1;

 END;

 select * from tbl_unit where unit_id in (rent_ids);

 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
END
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rent_id) FROM due_rent_ids`?

Comment: `IN (rent_ids)` will not split the string up at commas. It just looks for an exact match to the whole string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this all wrong. You can't put a comma-separated string in `IN (...)`, the commas have to be in the actual SQL code.

The right way to do this is:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_unit
WHERE unit_id IN (SELECT rent_id FROM due_rent_ids)
```

Or:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_unit AS t1
JOIN due_rent_ids AS t2 ON t1.unit_id = t2.rent_id
```

The second form tends to perform better in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks. I started the loop trying to handle the result set  from the execute statement without a temp table so after adding the temp table I didn't consider other alternatives.